# Unity2D: Let object jump up once when set active through script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi everyone I have a situation where a game object is set active through script. The objects have rigidbody2d's and polygoncolliders. I want the object to pop up a little bit when they are set to active. Any idea how to achieve this? I prefer the little pop up to be random.

Comment: apply a force upwards using `Random.Range(minValue, maxValue)` to the rigidbody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a script that you will attach to the object you want to jump, in the start function:

```
void Start()
```

you can add :

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

This will make the character jump upwards you can change the value to a Random value.

Comment: Ahh this works like a charm! Thank you very much :D!

Comment: Happy it helped :D